# In C# webforms, how to validate two textbox values in two SQL Server columns?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, webforms

I have a SQL Server table called ItemMovement that contains two columns: UPC & AlternateUPC.
I also have two C# webforms textboxes called txtbox_UPC_start & txtbox_UPC_end.

Usually, in my SQL's SELECT statement, I run a search query like this:

```
SELECT UPC
FROM ItemMovement
WHERE (UPC between '1000' and '9999')
```

A problem occurs that in my UPC range, some UPCs don't exist in my UPC column but are in the AlternateUPC column. and the UPC actually has different value.
i.e.
IF UPC# 1200 actually is an AlternateUPC,

```
--UPC-- | AlternateUPC 
 78487  |    1200
```

then I need to replace my search value (1200) with 78487.

I thought about using the exists statement in sql

```
SELECT exists (
    select 1
    from ItemMovement
    where (UPC between '1000' and '9999')
)
then 1
else 0
end
```

but because i need to get the correct textbox values in c# before passing them into the sql query, I'm stuck how to actually implement the logic here......
Am I on the right track?

Comment: What's wrong with `SELECT UPC
FROM ItemMovement
WHERE (UPC between '1000' and '9999') OR (AlternateUPC between '1000' and '9999')`

Comment: AlternateUPC is the old number.
Everything has to be as UPC.
I would have already used WHERE (UPC between '1000' and '9999') OR (AlternateUPC between '1000' and '9999') at the beginning if I didn't have restriction.

Comment: My ItemMovement table records daily sales records. The AlternateUPC is the old UPC# that was used maybe 1 year ago. All sales records now use the new UPC, which is in the UPC column, which is why i need to let the search engine know the records I am pulling include both the before and the after UPC# has been changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a possible solution myself.

```
(convert(bigint, UPC) BETWEEN '1000' AND '9999') 
            or
            (
                UPC IN 
                (
                    SELECT [UPC]
                    FROM [JS_Data].[dbo].[ItemMaster]
                    WHERE (convert(bigint, AlternateUPC) between '1000' and '9999')
                )
            )
)
```